# difficulty understanding ActionBar and ifRoom

Tags: android, eclipse, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

```
private void setUpActionBar() {
// Make sure we're running on Honeycomb or higher to use ActionBar APIs
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
}
```

What is ActionBar ? Is it a pop-up window or an activity or something else ?

One more question, why do we need to use 'ifRoom' argument in android:showAsAction attribute ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its an important thing in the Android world......its simplified through many tutorials and libraries..... here are some of the useful links ...

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

for popular ActionBarSherlock..

http://actionbarsherlock.com/

tutorial..

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidActionBar/article.html

there are lots more...